# Flow to postion by using SmoothScroll.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm customizing a Wordpress theme which uses [SmoothScroll.js](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#options-and-settings) but I'm new to using jQuery, so I could need some help.

My DIV is positioned on the left side like this:

```
div { position:absolute; left:0px; }
```

I want it to smoothly move to `left: 24%` if the page is loaded. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a little vague, could you provide some code, or a link to your site so that we can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish? It seems as though you will not need to use smoothScroll.js. smoothScroll.js is more for moving your whole page to certain areas on the page when you click the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is how the page normaly looks like: wp1022161.server-he.de/teststart and this ist how I'd like it to be at the end: wp1022161.server-he.de/test - maybe you see my problem on pageload, if not please resize your browser-window - the box just jumps to the middle of the page. If you resize the homepage (wp1022161.server-he.de) all the boxes move smoothly to their place - that's what I want my DIV to do. Maybe you're right and SmoothScroll.js is not the right way, I just supposed the author used it for that...